# Primeng table mutate custom component from parent component

Tags: angular, dom, primeng

I'm using primeng table for showing some assets.

```
  <p-table #assetTable [scrollable]="true" [value]="viewModelList">

      <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <tr>
          <th style="width: 17px"></th>
          <th [pSortableColumn]="'identifier'">
            Name
            <p-sortIcon [field]="'identifier'" ariaLabel="Activate to sort" ariaLabelDesc="Activate to sort in descending order" ariaLabelAsc="Activate to sort in ascending order"></p-sortIcon>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </ng-template>

      <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-asset let-i="rowIndex">
        <tr (click)="onAssetListSelection(asset, i)" [ngClass]="{'selectedItem': asset?.identifier === selectedAsset?.identifier}">
          <td style="width: 18px">
            <st-asset-status [jointItem]="asset"></st-asset-status>
          </td>
          <td>{{asset.identifier}}</td>
        </tr>
      </ng-template>

    </p-table>
```

Here you can see I'm using a custom component, 'st-asset-status' which is nothing but

```
  <span class="circle small" [ngClass]="statusColor"></span>
```

How can now change/update CSS of a particular row for st-asset-status for.e.g. 
I want to change 10th row (st-asset-status) from parent component.
Please provide taking into consideration best practice to achieve it.

Comment: Can you not loop through all the `st-asset-status` and write a if function to match the 10 th row and do whatever you want ?

Comment: Why can't u simply this.selectedAsset = asset (passed in onASsetListSelection)?